# Mac OS X equivalent of SecureZeroMemory / RtlSecureZeroMemory?

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, security, memset

Is there a Mac OS X equivalent of [`RtlSecureZeroMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562768.aspx) / [`SecureZeroMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366877.aspx), a function which zeroes a block of memory, but the call will not be optimized away by the compiler?

Comment: FWIW, if you're using OpenSSL, it provides the `OPENSSL_cleanse` function, which securely overwrites a block of memory with pseudorandom data.

Comment: Considering that OpenSSL did (and AFAIK, **still does**) use uninitialized objects on the stack as a source of entropy, I would hesitate to use it for serious security like this... The authors do not understand secure use of C. (This issue caused catastrophic loss of entropy generating keys when Debian fixed their bug.)

Comment: R, what you say is not completely true. Debian removed the usage of the stack variable **and** some other valid entropy sources and what's left was only the process pid. It was not OpenSSL's fault and using uninitialized variables as **additional** entropy source is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Write your own function:

```
void secure_zero(void *s, size_t n)
{
    volatile char *p = s;

    while (n--) *p++ = 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** to the question in the comments, why not `memset`? The `memset` function call could be optimized away by the compiler if the array object is no futher accessed.

Note that C11 adds the (optional) function `memset_s` and the Standard guarantees the function call cannot be optimized away:

> (C11, K.3.7.4.1p4) "[...] Unlike memset, any call to the memset_s function shall be evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine as described in (5.1.2.3). That is, any call to the memset_s function shall assume that the memory indicated by s and n may be accessible in the future and thus must contain the values indicated by c."

Comment: seems awefully compilcated and bloated. why not memset?

Comment: @Daij-Djan *why not memset* : because a compiler could optimize away the call if the array object is no further accessed. *seems awefully compilcated and bloated* : this is a classical way to write a `memset` function and I find it elegant and concise.

Comment: Dowvoter (if not @Daij-Djan ), thanks to explain why you downvoted.

Comment: it was me, I explained it and I just wondered why you wrote your own loop and now that I know better I retract my downvote.

Comment: Note that even if you zero a buffer, it's still possible that traces of it exist on the stack in ways you cannot safely or portably eliminate. One of the best approaches I've seen to deal with this is re-running the whole opertion with dummy data instead of the sensitive data after the result of processing the sensitive data is used, from the same caller. While there's no strict *requirement*, this will almost certainly result in clobbering of anything that remains on the stack from the first run. I've seen this technique used in cryptographic hash functions.

Comment: +1 I didn't know about `memset_s`. That sounds like the answer once it becomes available.

Comment: @DanielTrebbien: Don't hold your breath. Annex K is considered junk by most people (it was added based on Microsoft interfaces which were invented to derail portable C and promote the belief that the standard C functions are "insecure") and there's little interest in implementing it on most systems.

Comment: @R.. - *"Annex K ... based on Microsoft interfaces which were invented to derail portable C"* - No, it was not invented to derail portability. Microsoft designed it that way to ensure the destination buffer size was specified. Nothing more, nothing less. If it was adopted by everyone after standardization, then it would have been quite portable. CVE-2012-5961and friends for the win! (also known as Multiple Buffer Overflows in libupnp). Those safer functions would have stopped the overflows in their tracks. But instead of a SIGKILL, we got a Remote Code Execution....

Comment: @jww: I'm not rehashing the arguments for why that's wrong. You can find them in the archives of libc-alpha and many other places.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a Mac OS X equivalent of RtlSecureZeroMemory / SecureZeroMemory, a function which zeroes a block of memory, but the call will not be optimized away by the compiler?

In more recent version of the C runtime, you have `memset_s`. Its guaranteed not to be optimized away.

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
#include <string.h>
errno_t memset_s(void * restrict s, rsize_t smax, int c, rsize_t n)
```

OS X also includes the `bzero` function. But the [`bzero(3)` man pages](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/bzero.3.html) *don't* state its *not* subject to removal by the optimizer.

Avoid the tricks with the `volatile` qualifier because its not portable. It works as expected on Windows, but the GCC folks interpret `volatile` to mean memory backed by hardware for I/O. So you're not supposed to use `volatile` to tame the optimizer.

---

Here's an inline assembly implementation you can use. Oddly, `__volatile__` on ASM statements and blocks are OK. It works fine on OS X (that's where it was originally written).

```
// g++ -Og -g3 -m64 wipe.cpp -o wipe.exe
// g++ -Og -g3 -m32 wipe.cpp -o wipe.exe    
// g++ -Os -g2 -S -m64 wipe.cpp -o wipe.exe.S
// g++ -Os -g2 -S -m32 wipe.cpp -o wipe.exe.S

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string s("Hello world");
    cout << "S: " << s << endl;

    char* ptr = &s[0];
    size_t size = s.length();

    if(ptr && size)
    {
        /* Needed because we can't just say to GCC, */
        /*   "give me a register that you choose".  */
        void* dummy;

        __asm__ __volatile__
        (
         "%=:\n\t"                /* generate a unique label for TOP */

#if (__WORDSIZE == 64)
         "subq $1, %2\n\t"        /* 0-based index */
#elif (__WORDSIZE == 32)
         "subl $1, %2\n\t"        /* 0-based index */
#elif (__WORDSIZE == 16)
         "subw $1, %2\n\t"        /* 0-based index */
#else
# error Unknown machine word size
#endif

         "lea (%1, %2), %0\n\t"   /* calcualte ptr[idx] */
         "movb $0, (%0)\n\t"      /* 0 -> ptr[size - 1] .. ptr[0] */
         "jnz %=b\n\t"            /* Back to TOP if non-zero */

         : "=&r" (dummy)
         :  "r" (ptr), "r" (size)
         : "0", "1", "2", "cc"
         );
    }

#if 0
    cout.setf(ios::hex, ios::basefield);
    cout.fill('0');

    for(size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        cout << "0x" << setw(2) << ((int)s[i] & 0xff) << " ";

    cout << endl;
#endif

    cout << "S: " << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```